# If $x=p+q$ where $p$ is from $U$ and $q$ is from $U^\perp$, how to prove $p=$proj$_U (x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Suppose both $x$ and $U$ are in $ℝ^n$. Since $x$ is composed of its projected vector and its orthogonal vector, $x=$proj$_U (x)$ + $x$ - proj$_U (x)$.

If $p$ is in $U$, $p$ is in the orthogonal basis and so is the projected vector of $x$. It is necessary that $p=$proj$_U (x)$. Could anyone correct my proof?

Answer (score 1):

We have a direct sum $\Bbb{R}^n=U \oplus U^{\bot}$. Therefore, there is a unique way of writing $x=p+q$ with $p\in U$, $q\in U^{\bot}$. In particular, $p=proj_U(x)$.